# Can you set a maximum limit to an integer (C++)?

Tags: c++

If I never want an integer to go over 100, is there any simple way to make sure that the integer never exceeds 100, regardless of how much the user adds to it?

For example,

```
50 + 40 = 90
50 + 50 = 100
50 + 60 = 100
50 + 90 = 100
```

Comment: nothing more simple than a simple if

Comment: @Mansuro That isn't going to stop you at compile time.

Comment: You can use a ternary expression to enforce the value: n = n > 100 ? 100 : n;

Comment: There is already one - INT_MAX :-))

Comment: How are you going to use this? You could write a class, but code with an overloaded + operator that secretly doesn't go past 100 seems unmaintainable.

Comment: @sehe, that should be obvious from the samples provided.

Comment: @MarkRansom: true. I posted a simple implementation of a BoundedInt struct for fun and education

Comment: This is called saturated addition, if you need to google it. Keep in mind that `(50+60)-30 != 50+(60-30)`. Do you really want to clip the result at every step, or only at the end? What _is_ the end then?

Comment: @mwd: you probably wouldn't make it secret -- if you document the behavior and call the class `ClampedInt`, that should be enough of a clue no matter how terminally bewildered you think your maintainers are.

Comment: In the case regarding `(50+60)-30 != 50+(60-30)` it may be safer to interpret the maximum allowed value as infinity (which stays infinite) similar to how IEEE floating point arithmetic works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a fairly simple and fairly complete example of a simple ADT for a generic BoundedInt.

- It uses boost/operators to avoid writing tedious (const, non-assigning) overloads.
- The implicit conversions make it interoperable.
- I shunned the smart optimizations (the code therefore stayed easier to adapt to e.g. a modulo version, or a version that has a lower bound as well)
- I also shunned the direct templated overloads to convert/operate on mixed instantiations (e.g. compare a BoundedInt to a BoundedInt) for the same reason: you can probably rely on the compiler optimizing it to the same effect anyway

Notes:

- you need c++0x support to allow the default value for Max to take effect (*constexpr* support); **Not needed as long as you specify Max manually**

A very simple demonstration follows.

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/operators.hpp>

template <
    typename Int=unsigned int, 
    Int Max=std::numeric_limits<Int>::max()>
struct BoundedInt : boost::operators<BoundedInt<Int, Max> >
{
    BoundedInt(const Int& value) : _value(value) {}

    Int get() const { return std::min(Max, _value); }
    operator Int() const { return get(); }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const BoundedInt& bi)
    { return std::cout << bi.get() << " [hidden: " << bi._value << "]"; }

    bool operator<(const BoundedInt& x) const   { return get()<x.get(); }
    bool operator==(const BoundedInt& x) const  { return get()==x.get(); }
    BoundedInt& operator+=(const BoundedInt& x) { _value = get() + x.get(); return *this; }
    BoundedInt& operator-=(const BoundedInt& x) { _value = get() - x.get(); return *this; }
    BoundedInt& operator*=(const BoundedInt& x) { _value = get() * x.get(); return *this; }
    BoundedInt& operator/=(const BoundedInt& x) { _value = get() / x.get(); return *this; }
    BoundedInt& operator%=(const BoundedInt& x) { _value = get() % x.get(); return *this; }
    BoundedInt& operator|=(const BoundedInt& x) { _value = get() | x.get(); return *this; }
    BoundedInt& operator&=(const BoundedInt& x) { _value = get() & x.get(); return *this; }
    BoundedInt& operator^=(const BoundedInt& x) { _value = get() ^ x.get(); return *this; }
    BoundedInt& operator++() { _value = get()+1; return *this; }
    BoundedInt& operator--() { _value = get()-1; return *this; }
  private:
    Int _value;
};
```

Sample usage:

```
typedef BoundedInt<unsigned int, 100> max100;

int main()
{
    max100 i = 1;

    std::cout << (i *= 10) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (i *= 6 ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (i *= 2 ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (i -= 40) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (i += 1 ) << std::endl;
}
```

#### Demo output:

```
10 [hidden: 10]
60 [hidden: 60]
100 [hidden: 120]
60 [hidden: 60]
61 [hidden: 61]
```

### Bonus material:

With a fully c++11 compliant compiler, you could even define a *Userdefined Literal* conversion:

```
typedef BoundedInt<unsigned int, 100> max100;

static max100 operator ""_b(unsigned int i) 
{ 
     return max100(unsigned int i); 
}
```

So that you could write

```
max100 x = 123_b;        // 100
int    y = 2_b*60 - 30;  //  70
```

Comment: While complete, there's really no need to overload every operator unless you really need tight control over the intermediate operations. My class is much simpler and does the same thing.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I find it hard to tell what exactly is needed. I hate introducing leaky abstractions as well - the [Principle Of Least Surprise](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrincipleOfLeastAstonishment) should hold, even for silly sample code, IMO. I intended to show a _generic_ bounded integer class, as you can easily see from the way it is declared as a template as well. Consider this a _mould_. I'll be able to refer to this post in the future

Comment: Hahaha, well, I'm pretty sure all I needed at the time was a simple if statement. I must have asked this when I was taking my first coding class. But thank you (5 years too late) for the detailed response!

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
std::min(50 + 40, 100);
std::min(50 + 50, 100);
std::min(50 + 60, 100);
std::min(50 + 90, 100);
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min/

Another option would be to use this after each operation:

```
if (answer > 100) answer = 100;
```

Comment: Alternatively if you don't want to use the STL, you can define your own min function, such as `template <class T> const T& min ( const T& a, const T& b ) { return !(b<a)?a:b; }`

Comment: Why would you not want to use the standard library?

Answer (score 2):

[Yes.](http://codepad.org/lsA7FkSl)

As a bare minimum, you could start with [this](http://codepad.org/IYWfSs33):

```
template <int T>
class BoundedInt
{
public:
  explicit BoundedInt(int startValue = 0) : m_value(startValue) {}
  operator int() { return m_value; }

  BoundedInt operator+(int rhs)
    { return BoundedInt(std::min((int)BoundedInt(m_value + rhs), T)); }

private:
  int m_value;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own class IntegerRange that includes overloaded `operator+`, `operator-`, etc. For an example of operator overloading, see the complex class [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/units/example/complex.cpp).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to make a class that holds the value, rather than using an integer variable.

```
class LimitedInt
{
    int value;
public:
    LimitedInt() : value(0) {}
    LimitedInt(int i) : value(i) { if (value > 100) value = 100; }
    operator int() const { return value; }
    LimitedInt & operator=(int i) { value = i; if (value > 100) value = 100; return *this; }
};
```

You might get into trouble with results not matching expectations. What should the result of this be, 70 or 90?

```
LimitedInt q = 2*60 - 30;
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not allow overriding (re-defining) operators on primitive types.

If making a custom integer class (as suggested above) does not fall under your definition of a "simple way", then the answer to your question is *no*, there is no simple way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post but I think it could still be usefull for some people. I use this to set upper and lower bound:

```
bounded_value = max(min(your_value,upper_bound),lower_bound);
```

You could use it in a function like this:

```
float bounded_value(float x, float upper, float under){
    return max(min(x,upper),lower);
}
```