# C++: Is there a less verbose way represent custom numeric types?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I need to represent Volts, Ampers, And Watts and their relations (e.g. W = V * I)..

This is what I came with, but it seems really verbose. Any idea on how to make it more concise ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>


template<class T>    
class double_val {   
public:
    explicit double_val(double val):_val(val) { };
    double_val(const T& other) {
        _val = other._val;
    }
    T& operator=(const T &other) {
        _val = other._val;
        return *this;
    }
    T operator+ (const T& other) const {
        return T(this->_val + other._val);
    }
    T operator+ (double val) const {
        return T(this->_val + val);
    }
    T operator- (const T& other) const {
        return T(this->_val - other._val);
    }
    T operator- (double val) const {
        return T(this->_val - val);
    }
    T operator* (const T& other) const {
        return T(this->_val * other._val);
    }
    T operator* (double val) const {
        return T(this->_val * val);
    }
    T operator/ (const T& other) const {
        return T(this->_val / other._val);
    }
    T operator/ (double val) const {
        return T(this->_val / val);
    }
    bool operator== (const T& other) const{
        return this->_val == other._val;
    }
    bool operator!= (const T& other) const{
        return this->_val != other._val;
    }
    bool operator > (const T& other) const{
        return this->_val > other._val;
    }
    bool operator >= (const T& other) const{
        return this->_val >= other._val;
    }
    bool operator < (const T& other) const{
        return this->_val < other._val;
    }
    bool operator <= (const T& other) const{
        return this->_val <= other._val;
    }
    void val(double val){
        _val = val;
    }
    double val() const {
        return _val ;
    }
    virtual const char* name() const = 0;

private:
    double _val;
};
template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const double_val<T> &t) {
    return os << t.val() <<  " " << t.name();
}


class Amper:public double_val<Amper> {
public:
    Amper(double val):double_val<Amper>(val) {}
    const char* name() const {
        return "Amper";
    }
};

class Volt:public double_val<Volt> {
public:
    Volt(double val):double_val<Volt>(val) {}
    const char* name() const {
        return "Volt";
    }
};

class Watt:public double_val<Watt> {
public:
    Watt(double val):double_val<Watt>(val) {}
    const char* name() const {
        return "Watt";
    }
};

// Watt = I * V
Watt operator* (const Volt &v, const Amper& a) {
    return Watt(a.val() * v.val());
}
Watt operator* (const Amper &a, const Volt& v) {
    return Watt(a.val() * v.val());
}

// Volts = Watts/Ampers
Volt operator / (const Watt &w, const Amper& a) {
    return Volt(w.val() / a.val());
}

// Ampers = Watts/Volts
Amper operator / (const Watt &w, const Volt& v) {
    return Amper(w.val() / v.val());
}



int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    using namespace std;
    Watt w = Volt(66) * Amper(7);
    Amper a = w / (Volt(646) * Volt(444));

    cout << a << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

(note: I intentionaly omitted operator double(), since I wanted to avoid forbidden ops like Volt(4) + Watt(6))

Comment: Check out this Boost library: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_units.html -- it does what you need: unit conversions, dimentional analysis, etc.

Comment: Have you looked at Boost.Units? Looks like a perfect fit for your task.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is indeed a less verbose way in library form, **[Boost.Units](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_units.html)** which defines the SI units as type safe class template instantiations.

In particular, it defines the units [`volt(s)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost/units/si/volt.html), [`ampere(s)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost/units/si/ampere.html) and [`watt(s)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost/units/si/watt.html).

Comment: As usual in C++, all ways lead to BOOST :)

Answer (score 4):

[`Boost.Units`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_units.html) is a good solution for your needs, as it provides a respresentation of volts, amps, watts and appropriate operators out of the box.

[`Boost.Operators`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/utility/operators.htm) solves this problem for the general case of custom numeric types that are not SI units.

Answer (score 3):

If client code cooperates, you can remove logical operations using [std::rel_ops](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.4/a00989.html). `rel_ops` defines a bunch of logical operators in terms of your == and < operators.

However this is problematic -- it forces the client to use rel_ops, and rel_ops suddenly lets any class with an == and < operator to be compared with all the other operators. This is probably not what you want.

IMO the better option is to use the [boost operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/utility/operators.htm) library, which seems ideal for numerical types as it provides all the various operators you could want for a numerical type. You simply define a few basic operators, and it fills in the rest based on your specification. To steal from the boost documentation's example:

```
template <class T>
class point    // note: private inheritance is OK here!
    : boost::addable< point<T>          // point + point
    , boost::subtractable< point<T>     // point - point
    , boost::dividable2< point<T>, T    // point / T
    , boost::multipliable2< point<T>, T // point * T, T * point
      > > > >
{
public:
    point(T, T);
    T x() const;
    T y() const;

    point operator+=(const point&);
    // point operator+(point, const point&) automatically
    // generated by addable.

    point operator-=(const point&);
    // point operator-(point, const point&) automatically
    // generated by subtractable.

    point operator*=(T);
    // point operator*(point, const T&) and
    // point operator*(const T&, point) auto-generated
    // by multipliable.

    point operator/=(T);
    // point operator/(point, const T&) auto-generated
    // by dividable.
private:
    T x_;
    T y_;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Also, [Boost Utility](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/utility/operators.htm) contains facilities that greatly simplify writing all the operator plumbing in such cases.

---

I have recently done a sample here: [Can you set a maximum limit to an integer (C++)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616510/can-you-set-a-maximum-limit-to-an-integer-c/7616718#7616718)

Answer (score 0):

If you want something more lightweight than boost you can use [TU](https://github.com/KlasMvW/typesafe_units) (Typesafe Units). This is a header-only library based on c++20 that supports manipulation (*, /, +, -, sqrt, pow to arbitrary floating point numbers, unary operations on scalar units) for all SI units. It supports units with floating point dimensions like length^(d) where d is a decimal number. Moreover it is simple to define your own units. It also comes with a test suite...

*... note that I'm the author of this library.*